# tikz matrix align/decorate cellpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have a matrix of cell pictures, and want the first column to be right aligned and the second column to be left aligned. However I have trouble using the "nodes" key.

[example](https://www.writelatex.com/219094gjxmfg)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=3ex, row sep=2ex, nodes={draw}]{
            \draw (0,0) rectangle (-2.5,1) rectangle ++ (2.5,1) rectangle ++ (-2.5,1) rectangle ++ (2.5,1);
            \draw (2,2) rectangle ++ (2.5, 1) rectangle ++ (-2.5, 1);

            \draw[thin, gray] (0,0) -- (2,2)  (0,2) -- (2,3) (0,4) -- (2,4);    
        &
            \draw (0,0) rectangle (2.5,1) rectangle ++ (-2.5,1) rectangle ++ (2.5,1) rectangle ++ (-2.5,1);
            \draw (-2,2) rectangle ++ (-2.5, 1) rectangle ++ (2.5, 1);

            \draw[thin, gray] (0,0) -- (-2,2)  (0,2) -- (-2,3) (0,4) -- (-2,4);

            \begin{scope}[-latex, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=8pt]
                \draw (-2, 2.4) -- (0, 0.5);
                \draw (-2, 2.6) -- (0, 1.5);

                \draw (-2, 3.4) -- (0, 2.5);
                \draw (-2, 3.6) -- (0, 3.5);
            \end{scope}

            \node at (-1.25,1.95) [red]{\Huge\bfseries{?}};
            \node at (-1.25,3.32) [red]{\Huge\bfseries{?}};
        \\
    };
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

With this example I would expect to see bounding boxes arround the *cells*, however it only modifies the `nodes` *inside* the cells. I would like the frames to see the changes I make, once I actually add `column 1={anchor=east}, column 2={anschor=west}`.
Note that for shortness this example only has one row, however the actual matrix has several rows.

As a further perk I would like to add a label in the top left and bottom center of the cell. therefor it would be great to get those positions from the cell, since the actual cellpicture might be smaller.

This can be seen in this example from the tikz manual, page 204:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
\matrix [draw=red]
{
\node[left] {Hallo}; \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt); \\
\node {X}; \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt); \\
\node[right] {g}; \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt); \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

the border of the nodes is clearly smaller then the width of the column.

---

**Explanation With Sketch**
[image: Sketch of desired result]

To Clarify the desired result, I added the sketch above.

1. I would like to seperate the images in the Matrix by lines. Preferably as is done with the green lines in the sketch below, however an outer frame is acceptable.
2. I would like to align the pictures of the first column to the right and the pictures of the second column to the left. The (crude)`x` and (crude)`smiley` both have dimensions much smaller than the column, but are right/left aligned within the column respectivly (I thought `column 1/.style={node={anchor=east}` would do but I could not get it to work). Furthermore I would like to center the content vertically within the row. (I tried to indicate this with the blue linse)
3. I would like to add labels (wine red), in the corner positions of the Matrix cells

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. Can you include the end result you want to see via a matrix? Because you are using `matrix of nodes` but as you can see the TikZ example doesn't have it. It would be great if you can modify the question towards your final goal instead of the current problem. I feel that there is an XY problem here.

Comment: @percusse: I am not sure, but i assume `matrix of nodes` to wrap every cell into a tikz `node`. Meaning `\matrix[matrix of nodes]{1\\}` is another way to write `\matrix{\node{1}\\}`. The main point of the example is that the nodes drawn all have different sizes, while I want my nodes to expand to the dimensions of the row/column they are in. I want my nodes to fill the cells so to speak, rather than only encompassing their contents. Did this clarify it for you?

Comment: The description of `matrix of nodes` in the `pgfmanual` includes the statement "If your cell starts with a `\path` command ... the `\node{` start up code and the `};` are suppressed."  Thus no node is produced in your cells that start with a `\draw` command (which expands to `\path`).

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Thanks for the pointer, I obviously missed that. Do you happen to know a workarround as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the following captures many of the features you request.  I discuss the issues after the code.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, column sep=3ex, row sep=2ex,
  column 1/.style={anchor=east}, column 2/.style={anchor=west},
  nodes={draw}]{
  {\tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (-2.5,1) rectangle ++ (2.5,1)
  rectangle ++ (-2.5,1) rectangle ++ (2.5,1); 
  \draw (2,2) rectangle ++ (2.5, 1) rectangle ++ (-2.5, 1);
  \draw[thin, gray] (0,0) -- (2,2)  (0,2) -- (2,3) (0,4) -- (2,4);
  }}
  &
  {\tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (2.5,1) rectangle ++ (-2.5,1)
  rectangle ++ (2.5,1) rectangle ++ (-2.5,1); 
  \draw (-2,2) rectangle ++ (-2.5, 1) rectangle ++ (2.5, 1);
  \draw[thin, gray] (0,0) -- (-2,2)  (0,2) -- (-2,3) (0,4) -- (-2,4);
  \begin{scope}[-latex, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=8pt]
    \draw (-2, 2.4) -- (0, 0.5);
    \draw (-2, 2.6) -- (0, 1.5);
    \draw (-2, 3.4) -- (0, 2.5);
    \draw (-2, 3.6) -- (0, 3.5);
  \end{scope}
  \node at (-1.25,1.95) [red]{\Huge\bfseries{?}};
  \node at (-1.25,3.32) [red]{\Huge\bfseries{?}};}}
  \\
  x& y\\
  z& p \( \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{50} n^2}{\sin(\theta)} \)\\
  };
  % Labels
  \path (m.west) |- (m-2-1.north) node[pos=0.5,right,violet]
  {\textsf{Label 1}}; 1
  \path (m.east) |- (m-2-2.south) node[pos=0.5,left,violet]
  {\textsf{Label 2}};

  % Rules
  \path (m.north) -| ($(m-1-1.east)!0.5!(m-1-2.west)$) node[pos=0.5] (t) {};
  \path (m.south) -| ($(m-3-1.east)!0.5!(m-3-2.west)$) node[pos=0.5] (b) {};
  \draw[green] (t) -- (b);

  \foreach \i/\j in {1/2,2/3} {
  \path (m.west) |- ($(m-\i-1.south)!0.5!(m-\j-1.north)$) node[pos=0.5] (l) {};
  \path (m.east) |- ($(m-\i-1.south)!0.5!(m-\j-1.north)$) node[pos=0.5] (r) {};
  \draw[green] (l) -- (r); };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Firstly, as noted in my comment the `pgfmanual` says about `matrix of nodes` that

> If your cell starts with a `\path` command or any command that expands to `\path`, which includes `\draw`, `\node`, `\fill` and others, the `\node{` startup code and the `};` code are suppressed.

If you want a cell of this type to be a node, one work around is to put the material inside a `\tikz` command as follows:

```
{\tikz{....}}
```

Specifying column styles that include anchors allows for left/right alignment of columns.  You can specify anchors for a specific cell via `|[anchor=...]|`, which would also allow you to vertically center material in a row.

Finally giving the `matrix` a label `(m)` allows one to refer to the node in the (i,j)th cell as `(m-i-j)`, and to the matrix as one single node `(m)`, and so you can pick out various positions in the diagram in later `tikz` constructs.  Thus in the above code I have drawn the lines between cells via points consructed from such nodes.  I also used this for placing the labels.  Note that `(m-i-j)` is the node in the cell, not the whole cell, so you have to be careful which points you compute.

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, I still don't understand the question especially why we are nesting tikz pictures.

Comment: @percusse Thanks.  I too have difficulty understanding what the questioner is really asking for.  Putting individual pictures in an ordinary tabular, would be more natural.

Comment: @percusse, @AndrewSwann : The question may come from my lack in understanding tex. I think I am getting along with `tikz` quite well, while I have issues with tex (I still have no idea about the inner workings, and I have to look up most comments in awnsers given). Since I know how to draw lines with tikz the way I want and how to add labels at point (x,y) and have no clue about how adding text labels to the upper left and the lower right corner of a tabular, this seemed unnatural for me.

Comment: (continued) Furthermore I think of this as one big picture which needs the alignment and separations and not of 2*numberOfRows pictures, thus it felt natural for me to put everything in one picture enviornment. TLDR: Maybe my unfamilarity with LaTeX is the reason for me to choose the wrong tools for the job

Comment: It took me a second to notice, but this works best when the nodes in a row have the same heigth(notice how close the green line gets to the node with the large sum). A workarround would be to take half the distance between the max y of the top row and the min y of the bottomrow.

Comment: @ted Glad the code helped.  Indeed a more detailed solution would look at all boxes in a given row and find the heighst/lowest in order to compute the rule.  You may also wish to consider removing the `inner sep` from the first nodes containing `\tikz`, depending on what edge alignment you want.  As for the general principals, if you dig into `tikz` workings you find that `matrix` is based on a primitive tex alignemnt construct called `halign`; the corresponding latex construct is essentially `tabular`.  So replacing `matrix` by `tabular` is not so strange a thing to do.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem seems to be how to align several `tikzpictures` and place `labels` over them. One possibility would be to use `remember picture` and `overlay` options with a `tabular` environment to align graphics.

Please, look at next code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,remember picture,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\node[draw,minimum height=3cm,minimum width=2cm] (a) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,remember picture,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\node[draw,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=3cm] (b) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,remember picture,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\node[draw,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm] (c) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,remember picture,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\node[draw,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=2cm] (d) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path (a.east) -- coordinate (aux-x) (b.west);
\path (a.south) -- coordinate (aux-y) (d.north);

\draw[green,very thick] (a.north-|aux-x)--(d.south-|aux-x);
\draw[green,very thick] (a.west|-aux-y)--(b.east|-aux-y);

\node[red, below=3mm of a.south west, anchor=north west] {Label 1};

\node[red, anchor=south east] at (b.east|-d.south) {Label 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

As you can see, four diferent size pictures are aligned within a `tabular`. With `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` all pictures are horizontally aligned in every row and `rl` tabular options provide its vertical alignement inside the column. Once the array is drawn you can use any `node` as reference to draw borders, place labels or add anything else you want. Remember two compile twice to get everything in its place. The result is:

[image]

Comment: +1 for effort, but the drawing of those boxes was not the issue. I edited my question (see the very bottom) and added a picture of what I want. AndrewSwann's comment points out what might be the root cause of the problem (why all my efforts of setting `cell/.style` or similar did not show the desired effects).

Comment: @ted: Now I think you just want two align several `tikzpictures` into a `tabular`. You can do it `\begin{tabular}{cc}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}&\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\\ \begin{tikzpicture}... \end{tabular}`. Is it what you want?

Comment: Well, the tabular is not quite the ool for the job, since there is the label part (see point 3) and I would like some control over drawing the borders if possible, but that is secondary. Otherwise a tabular might be able to do the job

Comment: @ted: you can use tabular and `remember picture` and `overlay` in `tikzpictures` and outside the tabular draw borders and labels with tikz commands.

Comment: but the Issue with that is, how do I know the dimensions of the row/column? Remember pciture presumably yields only the dimensions of the picture which may be much smaller, see row 2 in the example.

Comment: @ted: please look at updated answer. I hope it addresses your real problem.

Comment: I really hoped there would be a solution without ´remember picture´ but yes, your awnser solves the problem. I would like to place the labels slighlty different, but as you wrote I "can use any node as reference", thus that is not an issue. Thank you very much. I still hope the bounty to produce further awnsers (maybe without the `overlay`). Thus I will delay awarding and accepting till Sunday/Monday.

Comment: If you don't want the `overlay` option, you have to draw everything inside one `tikzpicture`. I can think two options, one with `scopes` and absolute positioning and a second one trying to reference each `part-of-picture` to a previous one but you have to know which final result you want.

Comment: Sounds good. I will look into this. I just thought that `matrix of nodes` could do those coordinate calculations for me